# combine two blocks of text with equal number of lines in emacs

Tags: emacs

Suppose I have the following lines of text

```
aa aa

bb bb 

cc cc

xx xx

yy yy 

zz zz 

etc
```

Using emacs I want to combine the lines in columns:

```
aa aa    xx xx

bb bb    yy yy

cc cc    zz zz

etc
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the second part of the file (future new columns), kill it with `kill-rectangle` (<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>).

Go to the end of the first line, add a space, yank the rectangle using `yank-rectangle` or <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>.